# use cudaMalloc() to allocate when using std::vector<int *>

Tags: c++, pointers, cuda, gpu

I want to use below code to test how to allocate by pointer on GPU.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    cudaError_t err = cudaSuccess;
    size_t numBytes;
    vector<int*> a;

    numBytes = 10 * sizeof(int);
    err = cudaMalloc((void**)&a[0], numBytes);

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate device vector A (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Done\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I could compile it successfully by cmd :`nvcc b.cu -o b.o`, But when I run it by cmd: `./b.o`, I met the following wrong message:

```
Failed to allocate device vector A (error code invalid argument)!
```

I guess there are some mistakes during using pointer, but I am not sure why it happened.

Answer (score 2):

Your vector `a` has no elements in it. It is an empty vector. `a[0]` does not exist.

You may want to study `std::vector` and their [constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), which have nothing to do with CUDA.  Note the first note for the type of constructor you are using:

> 1) Default constructor. Constructs an empty container.

If you define that vector to have a non-zero size e.g.:

```
 vector<int*> a(5);
```

then I think you'll be able to get past that error.  (For example, this allocates space for storage of 5 `int` pointers)

Answer (score 1):

To have an `std::vector` use memory allocated on the GPU device, remember its template signature is:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<T>
> class vector;
```

that is, it takes an allocator class as a template parameter. This class could potentially perform the allocation on the GPU. Now, the C++ standard library allocator mechanism is regarded as not being very well designed or very friendly to use, but it is usable. Try [this (old-ish) tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4795/C-Standard-Allocator-An-Introduction-and-Implement) for writing a custom one.

H-o-w-e-v-e-r... this is likely not what you want. You would not be able to use `std::vector` in your device-side code, since most of its methods are hostly-only and much of the C++ standard library won't work / won't compile when included on the device.

A more relevant alternative may be using the [thrust](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html) library, which offers standard-library like containers and generic algorithms. Thrust has a [`device_vector` class](https://thrust.github.io/doc/classthrust_1_1device__vector.html) which may be what you're actually after.

Comment: If the objective is to have a host std::vector containing device pointers, how does any of this actually help?

Comment: @talonmies: The second option suggests switching objectives. The first option could work - the allocator could use allocate on the CUDA device under the hood. Perhaps I should make that clearer.